# Selenium - Automated Testing and Edge

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

Can someone point me to a website or information that discusses how to setup Selenium and write automated scripts?  I need to write scripts to test a web based application.   I know how to use Java and would like to do that approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it looks like you want to automate the MS Edge (Chromium) browser using Selenium web driver.

I suggest you refer to the steps below.

1. Download the Java binding of Selenium 4.0.0-beta-1 from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
2. Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from this [page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).
3. Create a new JAVA project and try to add a reference to the Java binding files by `Right-click the project folder-> Build path-> Configure Build path-> Libraries tab-> Add External JARs`.
4. Add the code below to your JAVA project.

   ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;

    public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "Edge_web_driver_path_here....\\msedgedriver.exe"); //Modify path here...
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
            //edgeOptions.addArguments("-inprivate");
            WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
            driver.get("https://Website_URL_here...");    //Modify URL here...

            //--------------------------------------
                //Your_Automation_code_here....
            //--------------------------------------

            driver.quit();
        }
    }
   ```
5. Run the code.

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code example as per your requirements.